# SimpleModal modal contents does not appear once closed and then reopened

Tags: jquery, popup, modal-dialog, simplemodal

there is a issue with my SimpleModal, i.e. if it is closed once and reopened again the contents does not appear in the modal.

you can have a look at nitinkabra.com/baldevgroup/contact.html, the contact us button on the bottom of page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to reload your cufón every time you open.

```
Cufon.replace('h1, h2',{fontFamily: 'StackOverflow'});
Cufon.replace('h3', { fontFamily: 'StackOverflow Light'});
```

Comment: Thanks, But the form submit still not works. It reloads the page on second time ..